# Only the PC that is plugged into the same switch as the printer can ping the printer, but other devices can ping the PC on the same switch. Why?

Tags: networking, network-printer

In my store I have sever POS computers running Windows 10 and a Brother network laser printer. Suddenly none of the POS systems can reach the printer. When I installed the printer in the showroom I added a Netgear switch so that I could plug both devices into the network. It was working fine until about a week ago. The printer has a static IP but only the POS system that is plugged into the same switch as the printer can ping it, so I am unable to add it to my print server on my DC. What is odd is that I can ping the PC on that same switch from any device on the network. As a temporary fix I just installed the printer on that PC and then shared it so the other POS systems can print to it. Does anyone know what may be causing this issue? I double checked the network settings and the static IP is in my reserved range on the DHCP server so should not be a conflict. The subnet mask, gateway, and DNS settings are the same as every other device on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this happen to me and the problem was the switch. Try power-cycling the switch and see if the problem resolves. If it does, try replacing the switch.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I never tried power-cycling the switch. That fixed it!

Comment: In my personal experience, Netgears seem to have that problem often.